# I would like to design a function using VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have say 100 output Excel files with column A full of variable names and column B with values. I have put them into separated sheets of one file. and I would like to get an overview sheet.

The thing is that the same variable is not in the same place (same column but different rows). I need to first identify the correct row number and then get the value.

My question is with the name of the variable and the sheet name available, how can I build a code to get the value?

Comment: Once you have the data in separate sheets of a single workbook, you can make the summary without *VBA*.  Just use `VLOOKUP()`s to retrieve the data from each sheet.

Comment: hi, I know the function Vlookup(). the thing is I would also use dynamic sheet name. How can I use the content of a cell as the sheet name for the range value for the vlookup. Tahnks again.